# Interclass variable reference

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

This is an example of some code I'm using to generate a form of populated values that will update itself when a field is changed.  I've been stuck for a few days reading and experimenting with calling a variable from one class inside a method of another class.  The reason that I'm attempting it this way, is to make the code more modular and readable since I'll end up having roughly 30 sections.  Also, as a rule, I don't usually use numbers when naming objects.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        Frame1()
        Frame2()
        Frame3()

class Frame1(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        ttk.Label(self, text="Frame1").grid()
        self.var1 = IntVar()
        self.SetVar1()
        ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var1).grid()

    def SetVar1(self):
        self.var1.set(2)

class Frame2(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        ttk.Label(self, text="Frame2").grid()
        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.SetVar2()
        ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var2).grid()

    def SetVar2(self):
        self.var2.set(3)

class Frame3(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        ttk.Label(self, text="Frame3").grid()
        self.var3 = IntVar()
        self.SetVar3()
        ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var3).grid()

    def SetVar3(self):
        self.var3.set(Frame1.var1.get() + Frame2.var2.get())

app = Application()
app.master.title("Window")
app.mainloop()
```

Toward the bottom of the code the error occurs for

```
def SetVar3(self):
    self.var3.set(Frame1.var1.get() + Frame2.var2.get())
```

and I cannot get past it.  Apparently I cannot call var1 in this manner.  It results in the following error.

```
AttributeError: type object 'Frame1' has no attribute 'var1'
```

When executed properly, the code should resemble:

```
Frame1
  2
Frame2
  3
Frame3
  5
```

So, what am I missing?

(A moment ago there were comments below, but they've since disappeared which really helps discuss this topic.  I'll pick this back up after some sleep.  Maybe by then the comments below will have magically reappeared and I can respond to them in turn.

One comment mentioned creating new instances of Frame1 and Frame2 to call in Frame3, but it wouldn't help unless these new instances shared the values from the already initialized instances in Application.  The other comment mentioned that I had errors in my code, but didn't elaborate.

While I responding to each comment, each disappeared and I was given a warning to edit my original post instead.  Did I miss something about the point of comments?)

Answer (score 1):

`Frame1` and `Frame2` are both classes, not instances. That's why you're getting an error in that line of code (`var1` and `var2` are instance variables, not class variables).

To make this work you'll need to pass a reference to your `Frame1` and `Frame2` instances (or perhaps, to those instances `var1` and `var2` variable) to `Frame3`.

Try changing `Application` to:

```
class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        f1 = Frame1() # save frames to local variables, so we can reference them
        f2 = Frame2()
        f3 = Frame3(f1, f2) # pass previous frames as args!
```

Then make `Frame3` use the parameters (here I just pass them on to `SetVar3` directly from `__init__`, but you could save them as attributes on `self` instead, if you wanted):

```
class Frame3(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, f1, f2, master=None):  # take other frames as parameters
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        ttk.Label(self, text="Frame3").grid()
        self.var3 = IntVar()
        self.SetVar3(f1, f2)     # pass frames on
        ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var3).grid()

    def SetVar3(self, f1, f2):   # take frames as parameters here too
        self.var3.set(f1.var1.get() + f2.var2.get()) # use the references
```

Obviously in real code the logic might need to be different. Think about what the logical relationships are between the frames, and let them pass (and perhaps save) references to each other as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you.  I had considered f1, f2, f3, but not passing them into Frame3 in that manner.  I'll give that a try.